Verify program source code on solscan/solana explorer
Basically title^
An example of what I'm trying to achieve:
https://solscan.io/account/CPMMoo8L3F4NbTegBCKVNunggL7H1ZpdTHKxQB5qKP1C#programVerification
How should I deploy my program in order to achieve this, or what should I do after deploying it?

Solscan is responsible for the program analytics and that will show up on it's own if you have enough transactions going through your program, e.g Tensor https://solscan.io/account/TSWAPaqyCSx2KABk68Shruf4rp7CxcNi8hAsbdwmHbN
You'll need to add the security.txt in your program and verify your program using anchor.
To add the security.txt, first install the solana-security-txt crate that is a self-reporting tool by on the best way to reach out to the creators of the program if a bug is discovered.
cargo add solana-security-txt  

Use it in your programs lib.rs
#[cfg(not(feature = "no-entrypoint"))]
security_txt! {
    name:  ,
    project_url:  ,
    contacts:  ,
    policy:  ,
    preferred_languages: "en",
    source_code:  
}

An example would be the soundwork programs that I've worked linked here: soundwork-list program.
Finally, for a verifiable build, make sure you have docker
produce a verifiable build with
anchor build --verifiable

